# What should I study to approach the frontier of integrable probability research?

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics

In terms of math, I know measure theory, measure theory based probability, differentiable manifolds, galois theory, some algebraic topology, and some representation theory. I have only physics 101 level knowledge of mechanics and electromagnetics. I wonder what math/physics courses should I take to understand the recent papers in integrable probability? Specifically, if I want to understand the [papers listed here](https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1664619#:%7E:text=Integrable%20probability%20is%20an%20area,integrable%20systems%20on%20the%20other), what should I study? If you care to elaborate, what physics courses besides math courses should I take to understand the physical background of interesting models in integrable probability?

Comment: If you're especially interested in their work, getting in touch with the people at MIT (more generally the people listed on this website - http://frg.int-prob.org/) is a good idea. They're friendly enough :) Borodin and Gorin also have a nice collection of lecture notes here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3351